# Financial proof short term student UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, london, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm doing a gap year to learn english in London.
I'm accepted in an accredited school (for 8 month) and i have sufficient funds to go (my parents will pay for me)
My Father has a new bank account ( 1 month old ) with more than 50 000 pounds.
Is it a good enought proof of financial stability ? 
I also have a bank account where i receive approximatively 2000 pounds every month from my family but sometimes i go over and use 100 pounds more (so i go under 0)

Any advice on how to go from there to have a good chance to get my short term STUDENT visa ?

Thank you

Comment: Your two examples are terrible. They would want to see that your not overspending your own account--and in fact that your saving money every month. Your parent will have prove where that money came from. See [Should I submit bank statements...?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/).

Comment: I am a student, i don't need to be saving money every month when my family is paying everything for me.
If i provide the bank statement of my father and his pay slips would that be fine in your opinion ?

Comment: What about a Bank letter that explains that i'm going to receive 1500 pounds every month ? wouldn't that provide financially stabilty proof?

Comment: How is the bank going to assert that you are going to receive 1500 pounds/month? Is the bank going to pay you that money if your father decides not to pay it for whatever the reason? Certainly not. Even if you get the bank to sign such a letter, I think it would do more harm than good...

Comment: If you submit just 1 bank statement for your father’s newly-opened account with no supporting evidence to show where the £50k balance came from, and your bank account statements showing you sometimes overdraw the account, your application is highly likely to be refused IMHO. See the duplicate question mkennedy linked to

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and straightforward, you need to show a bank statement of atleast 3 to 6 months (depending on the visa type). If you can show enough money in that account being held over a certain period of time, then it will not be an issue. A bank account opened a month ago will not be accepted and then you will also have to prove how such a large amount of money was deposited in one transaction. It will make your visa application weak